# Solve for x inside two tangents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am using trigonometry to determine what minimum focal length (i.e. $50$ mm lens) I need to use to get a certain pixel density of a certain object at a certain distance away. I can go into more detail if anyone wants, but here is what I have so far:

$$\tan (2\arctan( (Sv/2)F))\cdot \tan (2\arctan(( Sh/2)F))=(24^2\cdot 36^2)/(Ev\cdot 2 Eh\cdot 2\cdot Xv\cdot Xh)$$

Where

- **Ev** height of subject
- **Eh** width of subject
- **Sv** camera sensor height
- **Sh** camera sensor width
- **Xv** vertical pixels of subject
- **Xh** horizontal pixels of subject
- **F** camera focal length

How can I solve for **F**, such that I can plug all the values in and it tells me what focal length lens I need to use?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

What you want to solve is basically $$\tan \left(2 \tan ^{-1}(a x)\right)\times \tan \left(2 \tan ^{-1}(b x)\right)=c$$ where $a,b,c$ are known. Using trigonometric identities, this equation write $$\frac{2 a x}{1-a^2 x^2}\times\frac{2 b x}{1-b^2 x^2}=c$$ that is to say $$(a^2 b^2 c) x^4- \left(a^2 c+4 a b+b^2 c\right)x^2+c=0$$ which is a quadratic equation in $x^2$.

The problem becomes simple, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two answers.  For small angles, $x, \tan x \approx x \approx \arctan x$ which gives you a linear equation to solve. Since lenses come in discrete steps in focal length, this is all you need to know-pick one that is close in focal length.  For larger angles, which only come from very fast lenses, you need a numerical solution.  Even for fast lenses the linear approximation will get you close.